# SAS: Enumerated Group Variable with Missing Values in the Middle

Tags: variables, sas, grouping, enumeration, indicator

Hello I am trying to generate a group identifier variable in SAS that is observable for the first member of the group and is missing for all subsequent members of that same group. Ideally I would also like it to enumerate the groups as it goes down. For example, I would like to create VAR3 out of VAR1

[image]

I know that is STATA something like this could be very easily done as follows:

```
egen VAR3=group(VAR1)
replace VAR3=. if VAR1[_n]==VAR1[_n-1]
```

But I am at a lost as to how to do it in SAS. I know that you can do something similar to it doing this:

```
data zzz; set yyy;
g_obs=_n_; run;

Proc sql; create table X as
select a.VAR1, a.VAR2, case where b.VAR1 ne a.VAR1 then a.VAR1 else . end as VAR3
from zzz a left join zzz b where a.VAR1=b.VAR1 and a.g_obs=(b.g_obs-1); quit;
```

The problem is that this doesn't get me that enumeration.

Is there anyone who knows how to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your example:

```
data have;
infile datalines4 delimiter=",";
input var1 $ var2;
datalines4;
a,1
a,2
b,3
b,5
b,45
c,23
c,7
;;;;
```

The following get you the desired output:

```
data want;
retain _id_ 1;
set have;
by var1 notsorted;
if first.var1 = 1 then do;
    var3 = _id_;
    _id_ + 1;
end;
else var3=.;
drop _id_;
run;
```

The `retain _id_ 1` statement causes the `_id_` to retain its value (set to one initially) from one iteration of the data step to the next. Then, making use of the FIRST.`variable` it is possible to compute the group identifier. Basically, the FIRST.*variable* assigns the value of one for the first observation in a by group and a value of zero for all other observations in the by groups. Keep in mind that the data need to be sorted by group before applying the FIRST.*variable*.

Hence, if the data is not already sorted by `var1` like it is actually the case in the example, consider adding a `proc sort` by `var1` before the data step otherwise an error will be thrown.

Result (`want`):

[image]